# CSS float doesn't keep outer block element sized properly

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<ul class="blogEntry">
    <li class="title section">
        <span><asp:Literal ID="litTitle" runat="server" /></span>
        <span class="date"><asp:Literal ID="litDate" runat="server" Text="10/1/1000" /></span>
    </li>
    <li class="body section"><asp:Literal ID="litBody" runat="server" /></li>
    <li class="tags section">
        <ul class="tags">
            <li class="tag">Tag 1</li>
            <li class="tag">Tag 2</li>
            <li class="tag">Tag 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS code:

```
ul.blogEntry
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
ul.blogEntry li.section, ul.blogEntry li.lastsection
{
    list-style: none;
}
ul.blogEntry li.title
{
    background-color: #67A7FF;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul.blogEntry li.title span
{
    display: inline;
}
ul.blogEntry li.title.section span.date
{
    float: right;
}
ul.blogEntry li.section
{
    padding: 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

As is, the date will drop to a new line and float to the right. If I change the `ul.blogEntry li.title span` CSS and add float: left; The outer LI element's height shrinks and the bottom border cuts right through the spans' text. Advice?

Comment: (msg): Hi Spencer, I think you know what you mean. First, that was a communtity wiki. Second, that is my opinion. If you gave someone a task (like write ajax with pure javascript) and he comes back with the answer "use jquery", that means he is not able to handle that task. I didn't mean any offense. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please don't add *any* elements for clearing. Elements which only enable specific styling significantly breaks semantics and separation of concerns.

The simple answer is to add `overflow:auto;` to the container element (i.e. li.title) but there are other ways:

- http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html
- http://www.innovatingtomorrow.net/2008/03/24/how-clear-floats-css
- http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/02/26/simple-clearing-of-floats/

Clearing blocks are EVIL.

Comment: Yeah I'm definitely avoiding that. But the overflow property worked. I was under the impression auto was the default. Thanks.

Comment: No, "visible" is the default. Nice avatar btw ;)

Comment: Ah I just saw this comment. I think you're the first person to notice. :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.section {min-height: 10px;}
```

that should clear your floats for all your section classes in ie7 and 8. you may try floating the element above your date left to see if that works.

also, when floating something, you should usually set the width

Comment: Well basically I just want one to align to the right and one to align to the left. Am I using the wrong properties?

Comment: No you're not, but you have to compensate for the layout effect on the parent element. Note that min-height won't help you in <IE6and won't help you if you can't determine a height i.e. in a fluid or dynamic layout